# Ambiguity between 'Intents.SIGN_IN' and 'Intents.SIGN_IN' (CS0229) [CoreBot]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

When I run my ASP.Net Core in VSCode and I debug it, it creates a `bin` folder wher, like, a duplicate of my files are there. I guess it's compiled code or something.

Then I stop debugging and I have like 900 errors saying my variables are ambiguous, not knowing whether it's referencing the ones in my code or the ones in the `bin` folder. Obviously I don't want to reference the ones in my `bin` folder so I delete the `bin` folder completely everytime after I run a debug session to remove those errors. Then repeat all the time.

How can I stop receiving these errors without having to delete the `bin` folder all the time?